# Get total size of multiple files from a variable containing a file list

Tags: bash, disk-usage

I want to find out total size of some files which filenames may contain whitespaces:

```
cd /tmp
touch "a0 1"
touch "a1 1"
```

I put these filenames to variables and make a list:

```
var0="/tmp/a0 1"
var1="/tmp/a1 1"
var2=`echo -e "$var0\n$var1"`
```

Now if I check myself and print this list, everything seems OK:

```
echo "$var2"
#returns:
#/tmp/a0 1
#/tmp/a1 1
```

But if I try to get the total size, it somehow misunderstands "\n" symbol

```
du "$var2"
#returns:
#du: cannot access ‘/tmp/a0 1\n/tmp/a1 1’: No such file or directory
```

How do I make du process "\n" as line separator? Or maybe I have to create list in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to split `var2` line-by-line in `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
var0="/tmp/a0 1"
var1="/tmp/a1 1"
var2="$(echo -e "$var0\n$var1")"

totalsize=0;                                    #this will make script return 0 if var2 somehow contains empty lines only
while read "opened_file"                        #for each file in list do
do
        if [ ! -z "$opened_file" ]; then        #if variable is not empty
                tmp1="$(du -b "$opened_file" | cut -d"  " -f1)"         #get size of current file and strip unnecessary fields
                totalsize=$(($totalsize + $tmp1))
        fi
done <<< "$(echo -e "$var2")"
echo "$totalsize"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using an array instead

```
var2=( "$var0" "$var1" )

du "${var2[@]}"
```

See [BashGuide/Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Comment: Actually I guess the full answer would be: `du -c "${var2[@]}" | tail -1` or, if OP wants to isolate just a numeric value for reuse in further code, `du -c "${var2[@]}" | awk 'END {print $1}'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that if var0 or var1 contains multi-line list of files from the very beginning, this will not work. Thanks for the answer anyways.